# Blank screen on a cloned nvme drive boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, lenovo-laptop, nvme

**Problem:** A cloned hdd to a nvme drive with a Windows 10 system, on a Lenovo Y700 15ISK laptop boots into a blank screen. After pressing ctrl+alt+del it restarts and then Lenovo logo appears and it boots normally. After a soft reboot it also starts normally.

**Attempts to solve the problem:** I removed and regenerated the EFI partition, tried to change the boot order from the Windows boot loader to the nvmi drive in UEFI settings, to no avail.

**Question:** What can I do boot directly into Windows 10 when starting the computer? What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cloned the entire HDD or just specified partitions?

Comment: Yes, I cloned the entire HDD